# SQLite - Getting an FC at time of DB creation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, oncreate

DISREGARD this question, I found my problem...just edited the question to include the correct code jut in case someone looks for a correct database sample :D

My application force closes every time I run it. It only FCs when the database gets created, but if I comment the line when I'm creating the database, the app runs fine. (See code below for reference)

If I navigate to /data/data/com.mypackage/databases/ the database is actually there, it gets created, even the table with its tuples, so because of this, I believe my db class is fine. I must be doing something wrong in the main class (maybe not??)

main class, this is where I actually create the database object

```
public class myClass extends MapActivity {

 DataHelper dbh; // declaring database

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // =======
           // more code here
           // =======
    this.dbh = new DataHelper(this); // this line gives my app an FC, if I comment this line my app runs fine
}
           // =======
           // more code here
           // =======
}
```

database class:

```
        public class DataHelper {
               private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "track.db";
               private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
               private static final String TABLE_NAME = "info";

               private Context context;
               private SQLiteDatabase db;

               private static final String
                      sportsType = "sType",
                      units = "units",
                      date = "date",
                      tTime = "tTime";

               private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
               private static final String INSERT = "insert into " 
                  + TABLE_NAME + "(" + sType + ", " +
                                   units + ", " +
                               date + ", " +
                               tTime + ") values (?,?,?,?)";

               public DataHelper(Context context) {
                  this.context = context;
                  OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
                  this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                  this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
               }

               public long insert(String sType, String units, String date, String tTime) {
                  this.insertStmt.bindString(1, sType);
                  this.insertStmt.bindString(2, units);
                  this.insertStmt.bindString(3, date);
                  this.insertStmt.bindString(4, tTime);
                  return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
               }

               public void deleteAll() {
                  this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
               }

               public List<String> selectAll() {
                  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                  Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { sType, 
                                                units,
                                                date,
                                                tTime },
                    null, null, null, null, null);
                  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {
                        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
                        list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                        list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                  }
                  if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                     cursor.close();
                  }
                  return list;
               }

               private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

                  OpenHelper(Context context) {
                     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                              sType + " TEXT, " +
                                              units + " TEXT, " +
                                            date + " TEXT, " +
                                            tTime + " TEXT)");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                     Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
                     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                     onCreate(db);
                  }
               }
            }
```

What do you guys think I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: NEVER MIND, I found my problem

Comment: You should move the corrected code into an answer and accept it